# Bernoulli principle and vertical flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

I know that the [Bernoulli principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle) applies to a horizontal flow. I would like to ask with a vertical flow (liquid or air going from top to bottom), Bernoulli principle has been applied?

Comment: Yes, if the gravity term is included.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand yet. Can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bernoulli principle is derived by considering the work done by gravity and pressure on the liquid and then equating it to loss in kinetic energy(by work energy theorem).So yes,you can use it.